# NodeJS, readable stream, push large amounts of data at once

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to implement a readable stream. The data source is a measurment tool  producing a lot of data when started. 
I'm trying to push large amounts of data at once in my _read(size) implementation. 
When I'm starting the measurment and postpone the stream, so I already have more data than the internal buffer I got strange behavior.

- I try to push data of the requested size -> error, need to reduce it a little bit (in my case 32)
- Even the first push is successfull, the interface calls _read(size) again, when I trie to push the requested size, I got an error. The internal buffer is still full.
- When I start the stream before the data is getting bigger than the internal buffer, everything works.

Here is my code:

```js
  _read(size) {
    var bytesAvailible = this._tool.getCurrentAddress() - this._offset;
    var bufferStatus = this._readableState.highWaterMark - this._readableState.length -32;
    var bytesToRead = Math.min(bytesAvailible, size - 32);
    console.log("Cur Addr: ", this._tool.getCurrentAddress().toString(16),
      " hwm: ", this._readableState.highWaterMark,
      " length: ", this._readableState.length,
      " bytesAvailible: ", bytesAvailible,
      " size requested: ", size);
    var chunk = getData(this._offset, bytesToRead);

    if (!this.push(chunk)) {
      console.log("Error pushing.");
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Pushed address:  ", (this._offset).toString(16), " - ",(this._offset + chunk.length).toString(16), " Size: ", chunk.length);
      this._offset += bytesToRead; // set offset to next address not read;
    }
  }
```

And here the output:

```html
Cur Addr:  2000ef20  hwm:  16384  length:  0  bytesAvailible:  61216  size requested:  16384
Pushed address:   20000000  -  20003fe0  Size:  16352
Cur Addr:  2000ef40  hwm:  16384  length:  16352  bytesAvailible:  44896  size requested:  16384
Error pushing.
Cur Addr:  2000ef80  hwm:  16384  length:  16352  bytesAvailible:  44960  size requested:  16384
Error pushing.
Cur Addr:  2000efa0  hwm:  16384  length:  16352  bytesAvailible:  44992  size requested:  16384
Error pushing.
Cur Addr:  20010140  hwm:  16384  length:  32704  bytesAvailible:  49504  size requested:  16384
Error pushing.
Cur Addr:  20010160  hwm:  16384  length:  32704  bytesAvailible:  49536  size requested:  16384
Error pushing.
```

Can anyone help? 
Why the stream is requesting data by calling _read(size) even the internal buffer is full? Why the internal buffer is not getting emptied?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I miss understood the return value of this.push. I need to push data until it returns false. 
I have tried to push the chunk again when I got false because I thought it was unseccessfull.